# Symfony 3 - Declare and use the serializer other than in a controller

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I would like to use the Symfony serialization service elsewhere than in my controller. According to the doc ', it should be declared in a constructor. I did a test with the EntityManagerInterface.

I have this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

//...

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;

    }

//...

$nb = $this->em->getRepository('PagesBundle:UserCas')->getIfUserCas($mail);
```

I wish I could do the same thing with the Symfony serializer using something like :

```
$user = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
```

But I can not declare it properly in the constructor to use it later.

Can anyone help me ? Thank you

Comment: Why don't you use it like this $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json'); . This way you can use it everywhere.

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani Although I agree with you, I think he may want to serialize items in a service and that line would force him to inject the container in them which is a really bad practice.

Comment: I'm a little player in Symfony, sorry ^^'
Using this: $user = $this->container->get('serializer')->serialize($user, 'json');
I've an error about the "container" : Notice: Undefined property: Site\PagesBundle\Security\Auth\AuthCasService::$container

Comment: Yes, in fact I get a user who has two attributes, and an arrayCollection from a ManyToMany relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\SerializerInterface;

//...
private $serializer;

public function __construct(
         EntityManagerInterface $em,
         SerializerInterface $serializer)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

//...

$nb = $this->em->getRepository('PagesBundle:UserCas')->getIfUserCas($mail);
$this->serializer->serialize($user, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/serializer.html#usage) you can create a serializer object to serialize anything at any part of your code. There is not any need of injecting it as a service.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

$encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()]; 
$normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. However, if I want to serialize/deserialize an entity object ( which contains an arrayCollection and others attributes), I can't just use $serializer, no ?

Comment: I'm not sure about how serializer works with heritance but in the worst scenario you only would need to reattach those items to its parent. Not a big deal.

Comment: In the end, using the AythaNzt method, it works niquel, my paintings are also serialized. Thanks to you too! :)